# Remove singularity at zero from $-((i^{-n} (-1 + i^n)^2)/(n^2 π^2))$

Tags: series-expansion, convolution

The expression

```
h[n_] = -((I^-n (-1 + I^n)^2)/(n^2 π^2))
```

is real for all integers `n`. Although indeterminate at `n = 0`, *Mathematica* computes the limit to be `1/4` as `n -> 0`.

I'd like to use the expression in `DiscreteConvolve`, but even when I first declare `h[0] = 1/4`, a computation like

```
y[0] = DiscreteConvolve[h, DiscreteDelta[n], n, m]
```

yields only `h` and its explicit infinite summation representation results in "Indeterminate".

How do I make operations with `h` usable?

Comment: I do not understand your code. You write `h[n_]` then use it as just `h` with no arguments. ? `DiscreteConvolve[h,DiscreteDelta[n],n,m]` try it with `h[n]`, also do not understand why you use `=` and not `:=` in the definition.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are trying to do the following:

```
Clear[h];
h[n_] /; n >= 1 := -((I^-n (-1 + I^n)^2)/(n^2 Pi^2))

h[0] = 1/4;

Clear[y]; 
y[m_] := DiscreteConvolve[h[n], DiscreteDelta[n], n, m]

y[0]

(* ==> 1/4 *)
```

Here corrected your definition of `y` so it uses `m` as the function argument, but the important part is to understand why even with this correction your code didn't work:

The definition of `h[n_]` *would* be superseded by the specific definition `h[0]` *if* you directly asked for `h[0]`. However, when passed to `DiscreteConvolve` as an argument in the form `h[n]`, this specific case is not used and instead `h[n]` is expanded to the generic expression (which is indeterminate at `n=0`). The remaining calculation then never knows that the expression came from `h` in the first place. This happens because `DiscreteConvolve` doesn't hold its arguments unevaluated by default.

So you have to make sure this initial expansion of `h[n]` doesn't occur. I do this above by adding a condition `;n>=1` to the left-hand side of the line defining `h[n_]`. This makes it clear that this definition is not to be used for all `n`. Then the generic term `h[n]` remains un-expanded when it is passed to `DiscreteConvolve`, giving it a chance to see that there is a different definition for `h[0]`.